# Silence out quiet periods in audio file with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, filtering

I'm using ffmpeg to do some audio processing on phone calls. The raw calls have a left and right channel and my desired result is two mono files, one for each channel.  I was able to use ffmpeg's map_channel to split the file by channel but I'm noticing the resulting files have a bit of cross talk that I would like to remove.

Each channel has the primary speaker talking very loud and clear but you can also hear the person from the other channel talking very quietly.  I'd like to silence out these sections of the audio (i.e. make them perfectly silent but not remove them as I want to preserve the original length and pauses in the audio).

Does ffmpeg have a filter I can use to convert periods of low volume (or some other measurement that would isolate these sections of the recording) into total silence?

Comment: Using sox you could do a negative 'dcshift' to drop everything below a certain level and than perform an expand/norm on the result. Kind-of hack, but depends on the quality you are starting way and need in the end. A more complex but really clean way would be to invert the right channel and use an FFT matrix to subtract from the left and repeat for the other channel. Or treat the cross-talk as 'noise' and use the other channel as the noise sample to remove it from other channel, No matter which way, I, personally, would look at sox to do it... http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features