# Removal of low-noise echo from stereo phone call recordings

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I have phone call recordings which are dual channel with each channel supposed to carry only the voice of one speaker. However, they have some *echo* of the other channel. Any ways to remove this, in `ffmpeg` or `sox` or otherwise.

I am working on a Ubuntu 16.04 environment and using mplayer to play back the audio. A link to a 10s clip of the audio may be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xrchHvcluhDNGutYfCPpQi3cas_4Ogi/view?usp=sharing

I also looked at (almost) the same question: [Silence out quiet periods in audio file with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928716/silence-out-quiet-periods-in-audio-file-with-ffmpeg)
Not very sure I could follow the answer/comment though.

Thanks!

Comment: tell us how you get on solving this googling :  audacity remove echo from two channel signal

Comment: I am looking to remove the echo and then transcribe the audio to text, so just "making it sound OK" doesn't help much. I did find this useful-looking article though: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/removing-background-noise-in-audacity-by-differencing-stereo-channels . Unfortunately, after trying the following:
1. reverse-amplify (reduce amplitude) of channel 2 to match the "noise" level in channel 1
2. invert channel 2
3. add channel 1 and channel 2
The noise in channel 1 still remains "as-is", well almost. This I did in audacity.
Any further help most welcome please. Thanks!